# Select particular xnode using xpath

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xpath

```
<segmentFlightRef>
    <referencingDetail>
         <refQualifier>S</refQualifier> 
         <refNumber>4</refNumber> 
    </referencingDetail>
    <referencingDetail>
        <refQualifier>S</refQualifier> 
        <refNumber>1</refNumber> 
    </referencingDetail>
</segmentFlightRef>
<segmentFlightRef>
    <referencingDetail>
        <refQualifier>S</refQualifier> 
        <refNumber>5</refNumber> 
    </referencingDetail>
    <referencingDetail>
        <refQualifier>S</refQualifier> 
        <refNumber>1</refNumber> 
    </referencingDetail>
</segmentFlightRef>
  <segmentFlightRef>
    <referencingDetail>
        <refQualifier>S</refQualifier> 
        <refNumber>1</refNumber> 
    </referencingDetail>
    <referencingDetail>
        <refQualifier>S</refQualifier> 
        <refNumber>5</refNumber> 
    </referencingDetail>
</segmentFlightRef>
```

In above xml I want  "segmentFlightRef" tag whose child node "refNumber" have value "5" and "1". and sequence must be consider so I need only one node whose child node value 5 and 1 sequencially
Please help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath:

```
//segmentFlightRef[referencingDetail[following-sibling::referencingDetail/refNumber = 1]/refNumber = 5]
```

Comment: thanx for your answer but I have edited my question .I only need single node.Please refer it again

Answer (score 1):

**XPath** :

```
//segmentFlightRef[./referencingDetail[./refNumber[text()="5"] and ./following-sibling::referencingDetail[./refNumber[text()="1"]]]]
```

**Explanation** :

```
//segmentFlightRef[./referencingDetail[...]]
```

Select `<segmentFlightRef>` element having child element `<referencingDetail>` with criteria as follow :

**Criteria I** :

```
./refNumber[text()="5"]
```

have child element `<refNumber>` with inner text equals `"5"`.

**Criteria II** :

```
and ./following-sibling::referencingDetail[./refNumber[text()="1"]]
```

and have next/sibling node  `<referencingDetail>` with criteria : have child element `<refNumber>` with inner text equals `"1"`.

Comment: There are a couple of things unnecessary and/or confusing about your snippet. The dot constructs`./` are not require as you are already in the right context. Also, you do not have to use `text()` as it will automatically be atomized (and `text()` can slow down your code quite significantly)